# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Down' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I am trying to use a variable DOWN as a flag that I went to set when my internet goes down. Then when internet service returns, I want it to email me a log file (checkfile.txt). However, it seems that no matter how I format or use it, I keep getting this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Down' referenced before assignment.

Here is the code...I know, it is not the most efficient or artful, but I am trying to teach myself:

```
import socket 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 
import datetime
import syslog 
PIN = 12 
LED = 23

def is_connected(REMOTE_SERVER):
    try:

        # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is a DNS listening
        host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually reachable
        s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
        print ("Successful Test")
        return True
    except:
        pass
        return False 

def ResetRouter():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #this is changed from 'GPIO.BOARD' on previous version
    GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(PIN,GPIO.HIGH) # turn on pin - turns off power on AC control
    GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
    print 'Connection down - resetting now ', datetime.datetime.now()
    fout = open ("checkfile.txt","a")
    s=str(datetime.datetime.now())
    fout.writelines ("Internet DOWN at ")
    fout.write(s)
    fout.write (' \n')
    fout.close()   
    time.sleep( 20 ) # sleep for 20 seconds
    GPIO.output(PIN,GPIO.LOW) # turn off pin
    GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup - all pins low - ensures power is on


def main():

    if not (is_connected("www.google.com") and is_connected("www.cnn.com")):
        ResetRouter()
        print 'Resetting router at ',datetime.datetime.now()
        fout = open ("checkfile.txt","a")
        s=str(datetime.datetime.now())
        fout.writelines ("Resetting router at ")
        fout.write(s)
        fout.write (' \n')
        fout.close()
        Down = 1

    else:
        print 'Internet UP as of ',datetime.datetime.now()
        fout = open ("checkfile.txt","a")
        s=str(datetime.datetime.now())
        fout.writelines ("Internet UP at ")
        fout.write(s)
        fout.write (' \n')
        fout.close()
        if Down:
            fout= open("checkfile.txt","a")
            s=str(datetime.datetime.now())
            fout.writelines ("Internet RETURNED TO SERVICE at ")
            fout.write(s)
            fout.write (' \n')
            fout.close()
            Down = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Because you declared `Down` inside of an if statement, it's destroyed at the end. You need to initialize it at the start of main if you're going to use it everywhere. You need to learn about "variable scoping". It's crucial to programming.

Comment: This isn't true; Python does not have block scoping, so the variable isn't destroyed at the end of the `if` statement. The problem is that if the `if` condition isn't true, `Down` is not defined before it is used in the `else` branch. (Who upvoted that? Sheesh.)

Comment: @kindall is correct. Here's a specific explanation in the doc: https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value   Carcigenate's fix works though: just initialize the variable at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @kindall Whoops, shows how long it's been since I've written Python.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a boolean rather than 1 and 0 to signal true/false values?